# How should an amateur learn about ancient texts?

Tags: historiography

I would like to learn about ancient texts. To set a more concrete goal, let's say that I would like to know of the existence and the most relevant facts about the most important texts produced all around the world up to Middle Ages included.

This goal is not and will not be directly related to my profession and you can assume that my knowledge about history is at the level of a secondary school student. But I am used to learn by myself and to reading all kinds of texts.

What would it be the best way to proceed? What books or other resources can help me to start this endeavour?

My general motivation for this question is that I am a psychologist and I am interested in the human being in general. My direct motivation is that today I have read about the "Ancrene Wisse" text and I had no idea of its existence.

Comment: Are you aiming to read the original texts or modern translated/annotated versions?

Comment: I recommend Plutarch and Josephus Flavius ancient texts, they are full of adventures of Alexander the great and Julius Caesar

Comment: `produced all around the world up to Middle Ages included`  This might be significantly broader than you're expecting.

Comment: even modern annotated versions would be too much for me at this point. I am looking for a general perspective. I know there are some textbooks on "world literature" but I am not (only) interested in literature but texts in general. I am interested in the live of people in general, not specially their leaders. I know the amount of texts is huge, I am looking for an overview (I think all this is explained in the question)

Comment: The question here is a bit too broad to be answerable. Is there some specific theme you are interested in? Some specific reason you wish you'd know about the *Ancrene Wisse* before today?

Comment: The question is not which texts are interesting to me. The question is which texts are interesting to you, if you are a professional historian. What texts do you consider key to understand human history. Has somebody made such a list? Obviously each historian would make a different list. I am not interested right now in the interpretation that a historian makes of those texts in a history book, but in a list of selected texts. Or maybe a way to make my own list.

Comment: The question is too broad. There is no single discipline which deals with all "ancient texts". So you have to make a plan and study ancient texts of different civilizations separately.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I need, a plan. So, for example, let's say that I want to know the most important texts in order to learn how people lived during the Qin dynasty (just an example). How should I look for that list of texts then?

Comment: So you close the question because you don't know the answer. I see. What a weak community.

Comment: I answer myself with this link   https://www.reddit.com/r/AskHistorians/wiki/books/historiography

Comment: What are the most important texts? Some of the earliest examples of writing are commercial records and other documents that are little more than shopping lists. Funerary inscriptions. Maybe you prefer literature. History, religious hymns, myth, Or science, philosophy, etc? Are you interested in the history of the alphabet and writing forms, the history of the book as a physical object, in literary history, in the history of ideas? There are many histories of human civilisation, and some books on the history of writing and the book.

Comment: If you ask mathematicians what are the most important theorems, they will tell you. If you ask engineers what are the major breakthrough projects they will tell you. If you ask me what are the most relevant psychological therapies, I will give you my opinion. But apparently the ability of historians to synthesize is below zero.

Comment: @FCardelle As a professional mathematician, I doubt you'll find two mathematicians that agree on what are the 'most important theorems'.

Comment: @Denis but you could make up a list if you wanted. And some theorems are called "fundamental" for a reason.